# Do I need to configure both sides of a relationship with Entity Framework with Fluent API?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I'm new to Fluent API. In my scenario, a `Student` can be in one `Grade` and a `Grade` can have many `Students`. Then, these two statements accomplish the same thing:

```
modelBuilder
.Entity<Student>()
.HasRequired<Grade>(s => s.Grade)
.WithMany(s => s.Students);
```

And:

```
modelBuilder
.Entity<Grade>()
.HasMany<Student>(s => s.Students)
.WithRequired(s => s.Grade);
```

My question is - how should I choose one statement over the other? Or do I need both statements?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For *bidirectional* relationship like yours (i.e. when both ends have navigation properties), it doesn't really matter, you can use one or the another (you can also use both, but it's not recommended because it's redundant and may lead to out of sync between the two).

It really matters when you have *unidirectional* relationship because only `With` methods have parameterless overloads.

Imagine you don't have `Grade.Students` property. Then you can use only:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
    .HasRequired(s => s.Grade)
    .WithMany();
```

and if you don't have `Student.Grade` property, then you can use only:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Grade>()
    .HasMany(s => s.Students)
    .WithRequired();
```

Comment: I've always wondered, is there a good reason to use unidirectional one-to-many (when it's not a design choice)? In other words, is there a downside to always using bidirectional?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Only when materialized entity instances are used for data transfer with serializers having issues with reference "loops". Bu that usage is bad practice anyway. EF itself has no issues with that, and from modelling/querying point of view bidirectional perfectly represents a relationship with both ends multiplicity.

Comment: So the question arises: does it matter on which entity I will do the configuration? I think that it does not matter on which side, does it ?

Comment: @Eru As mentioned in the answer, if both entities have navigation properties, it doesn't matter. Otherwise it should be on the entity having the navigation property. All this applies to EF6, in EF Core you can configure the relationship from any of the entities.

Answer (score 1):

You just need **one**.This is more than enough for `1 : M` relationship.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasRequired<Grade>(s => s.Grade) //Student entity requires Grade 
            .WithMany(s => s.Students); //Grade entity includes many Students entities
```